# Android static config settings

Tags: android, settings, preferences

I want to define a series of parameters that should be modifiable otuside the app but should remain static during its execution. For instance I use my own REST API and I switch between my production and development server a lot, so I would like to have an external file that allows me to modify the URLs, but within the app I would like to be able to call it statically from any activity.

Is there any way to achieve this? SharedPreferences requires a context, plus I can't find a way to change parameters from outside the app.

Comment: public static final fields ?

Comment: as I said, I would like to have the settings in an external file, so I don't have to recompile each time.

Comment: recompile ? You should have to read the file at runtime and initialise  the fields

Comment: can you expand on that

Comment: What does expand mean? You put a file in your assets or in your sdcard for instance. When the application starts, you read that file and set in the class constructor all the files you need.

Comment: What I am asking is, what kind of config file should I use? a .properties file? What is the common practice in this case? If it's in assets, then I need context so I cannot set it statically.

Comment: you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: If if does contain only text, like an url, it does not make any difference. you can call file.propertiers or only file.

Comment: I still have the problem with assets, how can I read this file without a reference to the Applicatioin Context?

Comment: remove the assets part. Put it on the sdcard and read it with FileInputStream

Comment: SDCard is not an option, I should be able to pack the file with my app

Comment: you can not. You can override Application and create a static method that returns a context. To access assets and resources you need always a context

Comment: Ok, that method in my Application class sounds about right. I will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml config file and add it to your project. It will be `production` config file. Put `debug` config file on SD card. In your code, first check SD card if config file exists. If exists, use it; if not load the production version from application folder.